# Java автодополнение в консоли используя статистику списка слов

Tags: java, сортировка, поиск, консоль

Цель - создание консольного Линукс/Win приложения с автодополнением текста используя файл статистики слов.

Пример файла статистики:

```
бумага 223
утро 114
утюг 513
уран 22
тепло 144
```

Всего около 100000+ слов

Какой наилучший алгоритм для поиска и как лучше отсортировать считанные с файла слова с их статистикой?

Я думаю записать слова для каждой первой буквы в отдельный список List типа ключ-значение (SortedMap-TreeMap?) с сортировкой по значению, и разместить те списки в ArrayList. Когда пользователь начинает писать слово, список с его соответственный его первой букве сканируется на подходящие слова и они выдаются с сортировкой по значению. Это хороший способ? как практически лучше это написать, используя что из коллекций и какой алгоритм?

Comment: Первая буква слабоваты ключ. Если распределение первых букв принять одинаковым (что не так) то ты получаешь списки по 3200+ слов и как по ним искать, перебором. А что если пользователь начинает свое слово на "ПО" ... Ты в курсе, что 7% Русских слов начинаются на ПО, и еще 6.4% на ПР. Думаю надо строить индекс на основе двоичных деревьев

Comment: @Mike
Спасибо! А как практически построить индекс на основе двоичных деревьев? Я думал использовать Java TreeMap для начальной сортировки ключей, но это, похоже, не совсем что нужно...

Comment: К сожалению я джаву и ее возможности не знаю вообще

Answer (score 3):

Собственно есть два быстрых пути. Можно реализовать, перенеся твой справочник в таблицу БД

```
 create table dictonary (word Varchar(30) primary key, cost integer not null)
```

Тогда поиск будет сводиться к

```
 select word from dictonary where word like 'начало_твоего_слова%' order by cost desc
```

Встроенные базы довольно шустрые ([H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/))

---

Но если тебе надо использовать только java, то используй [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Только для начала оговоримся, что все твои слова должны содержать только русские буквы (привет кэп), и желательно только нижнего регистра.  Далее остается использовать метод [subMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28K,%20K%29), но с одной хитростью. Если ты ищешь слова начинающиеся с `бу`, то тебе надо передавать параметры в submap в виде `бу\u040f` (в конце символ, код которого меньше кода первой буквы алфавита) и `бу\u0450` (в конце символ, код которого больше кода последней буквы алфавита). Хитрость, но работает. Плюс тебе придётся сортировать результат, согласно статистике повторений слова.

Comment: Спасибо! Для получения submap, нужно указать от-до значения, но указать могу только их начала, а перебирать циклом все вряд ли хороший способ. Как здесь быть?
SortedMap здесь нес смысла использовать?